# Open Modal with PDF file on responsive view for mobile using iFrame does not work

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I have a function that when it is called by click event and when clicked it sends parameter `result` with PDF bytes and I set the URL in the iFrame and then show the Modal using as an ID `DisplayModal` for the modal.

When doing it in mobile view, the PDF does not load. I wanted to know if anyone can solve this issue?

```
  function GetPdf(result) {

        const bytes = `${result}`;
        var stringToArray = bytes.split(/[\s,]+/);
        var pdfBytes = Uint8Array.from(stringToArray);

        const bl = new Blob([pdfBytes], {
            type: "application/pdf"
        });
        const url = URL.createObjectURL(bl);

        //For Mobile view only
        if (window.innerWidth < 768) {
            document.getElementById("DisplayPDF").style.display = "none";

            $("#DisplayModal").html(
                $('<iframe>', {
                    src: url,

                    width: "300px",
                    height: "500px"
                }));

        

            $('#myModal').modal('show');
}
}
```

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Medical Records</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div id="DisplayModal" style="width:300px;height:500px" >
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[image]